# C and C++ see which compiler used for which code

Tags: c++, c

Im currently working on a big project that uses C and c++ code in one project using the extern "c" keyword in my declartions.

However I am unsure whether the compiler is actually doing anything with this as my output is the same when using the C keyword.

Is there a way to print something to the console to show what compiler was used for a specific peice of code in my project or a way to see if something is actually being compiled in C or c++.

For example I tried using `std::cout << something` in the c code and it almost worked, the error didnt say anything like std not found or cout not found IIRC which I found to be a bit strange.

Ive tried googling this and didnt find any results.
Thanks for any help!

Edit.
Im using G++ as my compiler and would like the code to work on other compilers. my c code should work on both c and c++ but I need it to be C as im using union type pruning. Im at work right now so I cant recall the error message exactly. I also get the same ouput changing file extention to .c.
Is there a way to see if the code is being compiled as C or c++ thanks!

Comment: What DID the error message say?

Comment: `extern "c"` does not mean using a C compiler. It means the C++ compiler (actually linker) will use C linkage.

Comment: Assuming a sane build system, the language is determined from the file extension. *"same when using the C keyword"* What?

Comment: Different compiler toolsets have different ways of deciding whether to compile a file as C or C++. For example, Visual Studio compiles based on the file extension. gcc/g++ will also compile according to the file extension, though you can tell it to use a specific language with flags. To help us help you, can you tell us which compiler toolset you are using (Visual Studio, gcc/g++, clang, other)?

Comment: I added information to the question. thank you everyone

Comment: `extern "C"` would be a compilation error if the code was compiled as C, so it must be compiled by a C++ compiler. As mentioned above, typically the choice is made simply by file extension (`.c` vs `.cpp`/`.cc`/`.cxx`, etc). (Whether you use `gcc` or `g++` explicitly in the command only affects linking, although there are of course options to set the language manually which you may be using explicitly or through your build system.)

Comment: GCC manual explicitly says to permit union type punning in C++ mode. So that's quite a weak reason to use a C compiler. If you don't like the formal UB there, you can always use non-UB alternatives such as `std::bit_cast` or `memcpy`.

Comment: Once you can, please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of some actual code that you are trying to compile, and include the compile command you run and its output.

Comment: I added more information tot the question about the compiler thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer your specific question about knowing if its a c or c++ compiler processing your code you can look for

```
__cplusplus
```

standard define

It's common to see:

```
 #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C"{
 .....
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the extention of your files for g++. If your file is .cpp g++ is used. If your file is .c then gcc is used.

Concerning extern "C" -- this is a cpp construct to inform the compiler that C abi should be used and none c++ name mangling applied. You can read on the mangling. As this construct has meaning for c++, i would expect it to be in a .cpp file.

Comment: There are some subtle nuances your answer fails to account for. For example, the C++ language is picked for `.cc` and `.cxx` extensions as well, not just for `.cpp`. It also isn't quite correct to say one or the other is used, as really what happens is a different backend is used for compilation.

Comment: Thanks. this doesnt answer the main question though. sorry!